# Mysql: Calculating running average for each Employee by day Monthly

Tags: mysql

I have this table that has the name of the employee and their phone time duration in mysql. The table looks like this:

```html
Caller Emplid Calldate Call_Duration 
Jack 333 1/1/2016 43 
Jack 333 1/2/2016 45 
Jack 333 1/3/2016 87 
Jack 333 2/4/2016 44 
Jack 333 2/5/2016 234 
jack 333 2/6/2016 431 
Jeff  111 1/1/2016 23 
Jeff  111 1/2/2016 54 
Jeff  111 1/3/2016 67 48
```

I am trying to calculate the running Daily average of each employee total_Duration by day each month. Suppose I have daily running average for the month of April, then the running average for the May should start from 1st of may and end on 31st of that month. I have tried doing many ways and mysql does not have pivot and partition function like sql server. The total employee who made the call changes daily, I need something that dynamically takes care of no of employees that makes call.

> The output should look like this:

```html
Caller Emplid Calldate Call_Duration Running_avg
Jack 333 1/1/2016 43 43
Jack 333 1/2/2016 45 44
Jack 333 1/3/2016 87 58.33333333
Jack 333 2/4/2016 44 44
Jack 333 2/5/2016 234 139
Jack 333 2/6/2016 431 236.3333333
Jeff  111 1/1/2016 23 23
Jeff  111 1/2/2016 54 38.5
Jeff  111 1/3/2016 67 48
```

This is the query that I started below:

```
SELECT row_number,Month_Year,Callername,Calldate,Caller_Emplid,`Sum of Call`,`Sum of Call`/row_number as AvgCall,
  @`sum of call`:=@`sum of call`+ `sum of call` overallCall,
  @row_number:=row_number overallrow_number,
  @RunningTotal:=@`sum of call`/@row_number runningTotal
FROM 
(SELECT
@row_number:=
CASE WHEN @CallerName=CallerName and date_format(calldate,'%d') = date_format(calldate,'%d') and 
date_format(calldate,'%m') = date_format(calldate,'%m')
THEN @row_number+1                                      
 ELSE 1 END AS row_number,@CallerName:=CallerName AS Callername,Calldate,Caller_Emplid,Month_Year,`Sum of Call`
FROM transform_data_2, (SELECT @row_number:=0,@CallerName:='') AS t
ORDER BY callername) a
  JOIN (SELECT @`Sum of call`:= 0) t
```

Comment: You should be careful with your tags to only tag the DBMS you are actually using. They are NOT all the same.

Comment: Thanks. I found the solution after digging some more.